# How to change the spinning circle colour on web3UIkit button

Tags: moralis

```
<div>
        {raffleAddress ? (
            <div>
                <div className={styles.enterRaffle}>
                    <Button
                        color="blue"
                        onClick={async () => {
                            await enterRaffle({
                                onSuccess: handleSuccess,
                                onError: (error) => console.log(error),
                            })
                        }}
                        size="regular"
                        text="Enter Raffle"
                        theme="colored"
                        isLoading={isFetching || isLoading}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className={styles.enterRaffle}>
                    Entrance Fee: {ethers.utils.formatEther(entranceFee)}
                    <br />
                    Number of players: {getPlayers}
                    <br />
                    Previous winner: {winner}
                </div>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div>Please connect to a supported chain</div>
        )}
    </div>
```

I want the spinning circle to change to red while it is loading. I'm using the web3uikit button. How do I change the colour?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use styled components - then you can target and style any of the component's elements directly (you can use your browser's inspect to find out what to use):

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from '@web3uikit/core';

const ButtonWithRedSpinner = styled(Button)`
  div[role='spinner'] > div {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
  }
`;

// in component's return 
<ButtonWithRedSpinner
  color="blue"
  size="regular"
  text="Enter Raffle"
  isLoading={true}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks I actually used chatGPT and it gave me this solution
`loadingProps={{ spinnerColor: "#FF0000" }}` and it worked.